# Asp.net dropdownlistbox selectedindexchange not firing from Angular template

Tags: .net, angularjs

I have 2 dropdownlist box on angular view (.aspx extension). So i wanted to fill up 2nd dropdownlistbox based on the 1st one. But 1st dropdownlist box not firing selectedindexchanged event as its on angular view page. So please help me to get ride on it

Admission.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" 
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="admission.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContentPlaceHolder" 
Runat="Server">
<!--=========== BEGIN COURSE BANNER SECTION ================-->
<section id="imgBanner" class="imgAdmissionBanner">     
</section>
<!--=========== END COURSE BANNER SECTION ================-->
<div ng-init="noRecords=false" ng-app="myApp" ng
controller="admissionController">
<!--    Main content goes here-->
<div ng-view=""></div>
</div>
<!--Controller-->
<script src="controllers/admission/route.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/admission/admissionController.js"></script>
<script src="js/removeItems.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

When i select item from dropdownlist it wont throw selectedindexchanged as it 
   is on angular view page. i think that might be one of the reason behind not 
   postback. I want to populate 2nd ddlist based on the selection of 1st ddlist 
   but its not fire selectedindexchanged event even after setting up 
   Autopostback true

Course.aspx (Angular view which contains dropdown)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="courses.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="courses" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>       

<section>
<div class="row">
<div class=" col-sm-8 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="sel1">Select Board/University:</label>
<asp:DropDownList DataSourceID="fetchBUName" CssClass="form-control" 
DataTextField="BU_Name" DataValueField="BU_Name" ID="ddlBUName" 
AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
<asp:ListItem>Select Board/University</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="fetchBUName" runat="server"  ConnectionString="<%$ 
ConnectionStrings:myConn %>" SelectCommand="spFetchBUName" 
SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="sel1">Select Class:</label>
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="form-control" ID="ddlClassName" runat="server">                               
</asp:DropDownList>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1">
<label></label>
<div class="form-group">
<a href="#!pay" class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" style="font-size: 
35px;color: lightblue;text-decoration: none"><span class="badge"> 
{{cartItems}}</span></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>  
</section>

<section id="aboutUs">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<!-- Start about us area -->
<div class="col-lg-12">
<div class="aboutus_area wow fadeInLeft">
<h2 class="title_two">Available Courses</h2>
<span></span> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>      

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
<div class="row text-center">
<div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="book in bookList">
<div class="thumbnail">
<a href="/w3images/lights.jpg">
<img src={{book.url}} alt="Lights">
</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<div class="caption">
<p>{{book.subject}}</p>
<p>{{book.price}}</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="btnControl1($event, 
book.subject,book.price)">Add To Cart</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what i want to execute after selectedindexchanged event fire

Course.aspx.cs

```
protected void ddlBUName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
SqlDataReader dr;
dr = clsAddClass.fetchClassName(0, ddlBUName.SelectedValue, "spFetchBUID", 
"spFetchClassName");
ddlClassName.Items.Clear();
if (dr.HasRows)
{
ddlClassName.Enabled = true;
while (dr.Read())
{
ddlClassName.Items.Add(dr["Class_Name"].ToString());
}
ddlClassName.Items.Insert(0, "Select Class");
}
else
{
ddlClassName.Items.Add("No Class found");
ddlClassName.Enabled = false;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you share more details or even code?

Comment: I have made SPA of 3 pages:- Admission page which has ng-view And course page which is view and has those 2 dropdownlist box. So from course page postback not firing after index changed

Comment: How does that help? Please add more details and code to the question.

Comment: I have added code in quetion